# Trying to call Invoke method throws an exception in a winform app

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I have a legacy project (Visual Studio 2003) which was made in the past by other people and now I need to maintain it. This legacy app communicate with another one using Windows Message Queues. One queue for receive, queueInput, and another one for send, queueOutput.

There is an action which is divided in six steps. While the action is being performed the progress is shown in the winform, let's say MyFrm.

So the action is started by instantiating a winform and then from its load event, first step is launched through a thread:

```
MyFrm frm = new MyFrm(param1, param2);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Load event:

```
private void MyFrm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BeginFirstStep));
    th.Start();
}
```

Then some threads are created and executed in cascade:

```
private void BeginFirstStep()
{
   // Do some stuff
   Invoke(new ThreadStart(FirstStepCompleted));
}

private void FirstStepCompleted()
{
    myLabel1.Visible = true;

   // Do some other stuff
   Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BeginSecondStep));
   th.Start();
}

private void BeginSecondStep()
{
  // Do some stuff
  Invoke(new ThreadStart(SecondStepCompleted));
}

private void SecondStepCompleted()
{
    label3.enabled = false;
    // Do some other stuff
    if (some_condition)
    {
         ThirdSteepCompleted();
         return;
    }
    else if (some_other_condition)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Do_AnotherTask));
        th.Start();
    }
    else
    {
       Do_AnotherTask2();
    }
}

private MessageQueue queueInput;
private MessageQueue queueOutput;

private void Do_AnotherTask2(object state)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new TimerCallback(Do_AnotherTask2), new object[]{state});
    }
    else
    {
        queueOutput = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\Actions");
        queueInput = MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\Response");

        queueInput.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(queueInput_ReceiveCompleted);
        queueInput.BeginReceive();

        queueOutput.Send(BuildMsgToSend());
    }
```

}

From another winform app, the response is added to this queue and then the event 
queueInput_ReceiveCompleted is raised:

```
private void queueInput_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     // Do some stuff with data received
     Invoke(new ThreadStart(ThirdStepCompleted)); // HERE IT SOMETIMES CRASHES (NOT ALWAYS).
}

private void ThirdStepCompleted()
{
        // Do some other stuff
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BeginFourthStep));
        th.Start();
}
```

and so on... with the rest of the steps.

The problem is:

Sometimes (not always), program crashes at queueInput_ReceiveCompleted handler method when performing the Invoke. The error says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot call Invoke or InvokeAsync on
>   a control until the window handle has been created.

I know, it is a complex and difficult code to understand, but it was designed as is....

Comment: Are you creating controls on different threads?

Comment: @mm8 No, Only updating some Control properties, but it does not throws any execption despite not using invokerequired.

Comment: Exactly where are you getting this exception? Please provide a MCVE of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: @mm8 within queueInput_ReceiveCompleted method when calling Invoke.

Comment: Can't you check whether the IsHandleCreated property returns true and call the CreateHandle method if it doesn't?

Comment: @mm8 I can try but I wonder if this will cause two handles being created on different threads...